# Minecraft Gamerules not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my friend were playing Minecraft, and I created a world with cheats de-activated. When I opened it to LAN, I activated cheats, and changed the two game rules keepInventory (True) and mobGriefing (false). But, my items dropped when I died, and a Creeper blew up part of my Mineshaft.

Later, my friend started up a Singleplayer world (with cheats), enabled those two gamerules (to the same as on our LAN), and the same results happened.

I am pretty sure I put the command in right, seeing as I did:

```
/gamerule [hit tab until I got to the rule I wanted to change] [hit tab until I got to the way I wanted to change it] and hit enter.
```

How do I get them to work?

Comment: That *is* puzzling. Can you use an NBT reader to open the save's level.dat to see what the gamerules are set to now?

Comment: What's the version?

Comment: Are you running _**EXACTLY**_ `/gamerule keepInventory true`?

Comment: pretty sure, I typed /gamerule, then used the tab button to cycle through modifiers for it

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the world originally had cheats off, maybe try copy and pasting this commands into your chat: /gamerule keepInventory true and /gamerule mobGriefing false

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493, my version (as on the loader) was set to the most recent (it would auto change depending on it).

Comment: As @SevenSidedDie said, can you use an NBT reader (like NBTExplorer) to open the save's level.dat to see what the gamerules are set to now?

Comment: I can go try that @ArceusMaster0493

Comment: Just saw [another report of gamerule not working on 1.8.3](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207424/minecraft-server-help). I suspect it may be a bug in this version.

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure that the following standards are met:

1. Cheats are ON
2. You made sure that the 'g' in gamerule is lowercase
3. The I in keepInventory is capital
4. true is not capitalized.

If all else fails, you might have to re-install Minecraft. If that doesn't work, I have no idea what will. Happy Crafting!

Comment: As I stated in the first segment of the question, the first world does not have cheats enabled (it did enable them with LAN), but the second world does meet all of those requirements.

Comment: Very strange. I'll have to look into this more.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, if you do `/gamerule set (example gamerule)` then it will of claimed to of done the gamerule when it has actually not, but if you just put `/gamerule (example gamerule)` then it will work fine.